# How do I represent input-process-output in pseudo-code?

Tags: pseudocode

For my class in programming I was given this assignment:

> Write pseudocode to represent the logic of a program that allows a
>   user to enter two values then outputs the product of the two values

I wrote:

```
start
  input takeOne
  input takeTwo
  output takeONe, takeTwo
Stop
```

Or

```
Start    
   Declarations
        ouPutTwo = takeOne, takeTwo

   Input takeOne, takeTwo 

   Output ouPutTwo

Stop
```

Is this right? should I go like this?

```
Start    
   Declarations
        ouPutTwo = takeOne, takeTwo

   Input takeOne takeTwo 

   Output ouPutTwo

Stop
```

Comment: Don't you have notes from your class that would help you resolve this? Perhaps try writing it out in english how you would solve it then turn it into pseudocode from there?

Comment: "output the product"... where are you doing the multiplication? All you're doing is asking for some stuff, and spitting that stuff back out.

Comment: @MarcB I think I should do this then...

Comment: @MarcB start input takeOne, takeTwo output takeOne, takeTwo Stop?

Comment: @AlexWhite they haven't taught me this yet.

Comment: @MarcB there is no multiplications. I thought you had to declare the type in order to input anything. I'm getting ahead of myself. I just read the book, the teacher hasn't taught this subject yet.

Comment: @MarcB is this a better way? I just edited my post.

Comment: I hope you don't mind me asking, but do you know that 'product of' means 'result of them multiplied together'? So basically it is asking for pseudocode to take in two values and return the result of those two values multiplied together.

Comment: @alexWhite I didn't. Thought it was outputting the value that was input in. Thanks.